# Can't exit selection list and run selectend script

Tags: bash, git-bash

I want to create a project launch helper bash script for my Angular workspace.
A separate script lists the projects and stores them in the `$projects` variable.

It lists the projects in order as I want but after selection, I can't exit the do-while loop, so it can continue to the next step, which is to run the selected script.
By the dos, the `break` key should do the trick, but in my case it terminates the whole terminal window.

My code:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

projects=$(node ./scripts/get-projects/index.js)
echo "Select a project to run:"

# Define the menu list here
select project in $projects
do
    echo "Selected project: $project"
done

echo "Running: $project"

ng serve --project="$project"
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: _I can't exit the do-while loop_ : I don't see such a loop in the code you posted.

Comment: `select` loops until you execute a `break` statement in the `do...done` block. As you do not have any `break` statement it loops forever...

Comment: @RenaudPacalet, thanks for your comment! I was not thinking about this option, only about hitting the break keyboard key.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop

```
select project in $projects
do
    echo "Selected project: $project"
done
```

should be something like the following:

```
for project in $projects
do
    echo "Select project '$project' ? [y|N] => \c" ; read sel
    if [ -z "${sel}" ] ; then  sel="N" ; fi
    case ${sel} in
            y* | Y* ) DOIT=1 ; break ;;
            * ) DOIT=0 ;;
    esac
done

if [ ${DOIT} -eq 1 ]
then
    echo "Running: $project"
    ng serve --project="$project"
    exit
fi
```